# How to add body to the HTTP GET request in Angular

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm trying to add the body to the HTTP GET request. But not able to add

I have tried with RequestOptions but it did not work.

For the mentioned code, POST Request is working but GET is not working

```
getlist(name : string) : Observable<Object[]> {

var body = {
  "listname" : name
}

 return this.http.post<any>("http:/regsd.com/api/lists/",body)
}
```

Comment: You must read the document about `HTTPPOST` and `HTTPGET`

Comment: You can not send body in GET. Check API implementation on server side.

Comment: You cannot add body to GET

Comment: maybe you mean query params.

Comment: Okay ! Thank You

Comment: Get is not supposed to have a body. If your service is expecting one you should consider reengineering your server API to POST.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/8103819

Answer (score 2):

You can pass query params in GET request.

```
getlist(name : string) : Observable<Object[]> {
  return this.http.get<any>(`http:/regsd.com/api/lists/?listname=${name}`);
}
```

Body can be only set in POST and other verb like PUT in HTTP.